# How to add custom action bar with navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

I tried using Custom Action bar as:

```
bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        bar.setCustomView(R.layout.xyz);
```

but navigation drawer becomes invisible.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, but I found a way to go around the problem. You need to set:

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.xyz);
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

Then, it will show navigation drawer + icon.

If you don't want the icon to be visible, you can put a transparent image (just make transparent image `transparent.png` and put in drawable folder) instead of app icon. You can do that by defining new style for Action Bar (`styles.xml`):

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Adding transparent icon is not working, can you please tell me the solution for removing app icon from action bar in above case.

Comment: @mark for removing app icon actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent); works

Answer (score 1):

For me worked:

`getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.xyz);
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);`

Answer (score 1):

actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);